# Blazor MAUI Hybrid There is no browser renderer with ID 0

Tags: c#, webview, blazor, maui

Anyone know what this error means and how I can figure out what to do about it? This is from start of a Blazor MAUI Hybrid app .NET 8 preview 6. Restarting the app seems to work but intermittently get this error.

```
blazor.webview.js:1  Error: There is no browser renderer with ID 0.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.IpcReceiver.OnMessageReceivedAsync(/s/PageContext pageContext, String message)
   at /s/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.WebViewManager.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<<MessageReceived>b__0>d.MoveNext()
NotifyUnhandledException @ blazor.webview.js:1
```

Comment: Did you try to copy your code to the .net 7.0 or .net 6.0 project to detect if the exception still appear?

Comment: You suggest rolling back to .NET 7?

Comment: No, I just want check if the problem only appear in the .net 8.0.

Comment: We have rolled back the app to .NET 7 and we'll see if it happens again

Comment: Rolled back to .NET 7 and so far haven't seen this error again. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: So it seems a special issue in the .net 8.0, you can report it on the github.

Comment: I get this error with .NET 7; I don't think it's specific to .NET 8.